# How to use wordpress default image editor to our forntend side code?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The wordpress is give the facility to use image editor of the backend to front end to reusability of the code ?.

I am trying to edit the image in the front-side. Have any idea wold be appriciated.

Comment: I think you can use any plugin for front end.

Comment: Thanks for answer, is there any solution by custom code because I want only image rotation support.